# oozie throwing error java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter, but class was expected

Tags: java, oozie

I have written a mapreduce class in which I am using a counter when I execute that mapreduce code I get this error

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter, but class was expected
    at MyProg.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at MyProg.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:454)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
```

Can anyone suggest why do i get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a version conflict between Oozie and the version of Hadoop you have vs the version Oozie was built against. Take a look at this (resolved) ticket for hadoop: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3697

There's a couple of patches in that ticket that you can try and run.